# How to model multiple one-to-many relationship with value types in Swift

Tags: swift, relationship, data-modeling

I'm designing the model layer for an application. I'm trying to use value types in Swift (i.e. `structs`). The reason for this is that they make undo operations more easy as I can store the 'current' version of a struct to be restored later and if I hand out values to the rest of my application I can be sure that they aren't modified (possibly by the threads).
But I've a problem when the model gets more relationships.
Imagine I've a `Author` and `Book` struct:

```
struct Book {
    title: String
}

struct Author {
    name: String
    books: [Book]
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to add a `Shelve` struct, to manage blobs of books:

```
struct Shelve {
    books: [Book]
}
```

As the `Book`'s are value types, the same book can't belong to both the `Author` and the `Shelve` at the same time. This is of course possible with reference types, but then I have to make copies of values I hand off to the rest of the application or which I store for undo operations.

I could also make the `Book` conform the `Identifiable` or some sort and only store the `id` of the `Book` in the `Author` or `Shelve`, but then I'm kind of making my own reference type system.

How could I best manage these kind of relationships between the entities? Going for storing `id`'s, or going for (real) reference types and making copies all along the way? Are there other strategies I could follow?

Comment: Maybe add `Author` as properly of `Book`?

Comment: That would give rise to the same problem, no? Multiple `Book`’s won’t be able to share the same `Author`.

Comment: It will be a copy each time, also for Author.books, where you state _This works fine_. Let's say you create a _Book_, then an _Author_ for that book, and later in you code you change the book's title, then that change will not be reflected in the book in _Author.books_. You need some form of identity if you want to refer to these entities later in code.